# Laravel pagination: why are some pages returning undefined offset: 0?

Tags: php, laravel, pagination, laravel-blade, undefined-index

So I have a list of about 1700 records and I want to show it paginated with five records per page and for the most part this is working with the code I have currently. The problem I am having is that when I go to certain pages I get this error: `Undefined offset: 0 (View: Project\resources\views\minors\index.blade.php)`. When I `var_dump` the data I send to the view it contains an item with the index 0.

Controller method:

```
    public function index( Request $request )
    {
        $locations = Location::all();
        $minors = Module::paginate(5);
        return view('minors.index')->with(compact('minors','locations'));
    }
```

View:

```
    @if(isset($minors))
        @foreach($minors as $key => $minor)
            <a id="minorLinkId" class="minorLink" href="{{ Action('MinorController@show', $minor->id)  }}">
                <div id="minorContainerId" class="minorContainer">
                    <div class="textContainer">
                        <h3>{{$minor->name}}</h3>
                        <p>{{@strip_tags($minor->subject)}}</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="imageContainer">
                        <img src="{{asset('img/person-placeholder.jpg')}}">
                        <ul>
                            <li>ECTs: {{$minor->ects}}</li>
                            <li>Taal: {{$minor->language}}</li>
                            <li>Niveau: {{$minor->level}}</li>
                            <li>{{$minor->locations[0]->Name }}</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </a>
        @endforeach
           {{ $minors->links() }}
    @endif
```

First part of `var_dump($minors)` placed before `return view('minors.index')` in the index method of the controller:

```
object(Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator)#486 (11) { ["total":protected]=> int(1710) ["lastPage":protected]=> int(342) ["items":protected]=> object(Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection)#479 (1) { ["items":protected]=> array(5) { [0]=> object(App\Module)#478 (26) { ["guarded":protected]=> array(0) { } ["connection":protected]=> string(5) "mysql" ["table":protected]=> string(7) "modules" ["primaryKey":protected]=> string(2) "id" ["keyType":protected]=> string(3) "int" ["incrementing"]=> bool(true) ["with":protected]=> array(0) { } ["withCount":protected]=> array(0) { } ["perPage":protected]=> int(15) ["exists"]=> bool(true) ["wasRecentlyCreated"]=> bool(false) ["attributes":protected]=> array(33) {
```

I suspect the problem has something to do with the return statement in the index method of the controller but I don't understand why it only happens on certain pages.

I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is because of this line

```
<li>{{$minor->locations[0]->Name }}</li>
```

You are trying to access the index zero which does not exist because the locations array is empty or undefined. You can replace the above code with the following code:

```
@if(sizeof($minor->locations) > 0)
    <li>{{$minor->locations[0]->Name }}</li>
@endif
```

The **sizeof()** function counts elements in an array or properties in an object. It returns the number of elements in an array.